# MFMessageComposeViewController with Whitespace

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

I'm using `MFMessageComposeViewController` for in-app SMS. The problem is that when I have an `NSString` with whitespace to assign to body, it will remove all whitespaces. Below code demonstrates the issue. Interesting thing is that it works when I try to copy the same text to clipboard and paste into the sms app.

```
- (void)sendSMS {
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
       [controller setBody:@"    aaa    aaa"];
       controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
       controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
       [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
    [controller release];
}
//it becomes "aaa aaa" on the SMS message box when controller shows up.
```

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just curious: are the whitespaces in your string tabs or spaces?

Comment: I would try assigning your string constant to a variable and right before you call setBody put an NSLog call with the variable and see how it is displayed (use the same variable in the setBody call). It'll probably print the way you want but at least it give you a little info. You can also put an NSLog([controller body]) call AFTER you call setBody and see how that displays.

Comment: I've already done it. NSLog and controller.body shows it with whitespaces which is correct. But, on the controller message box is showing it without whitespace.

Comment: That's what I figured but at least you've ruled some things out.

Comment: It's plain text. MFMessageComposeViewController body can only accept text.

Comment: yes i had the same problem can any one figured out about that problem/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to still be a problem 5/2012.  However you can force the whitespace with &nbsp. Not the best option, but it works.  The MFMailComposeController will also drop leading whitespace on the body and the same method works.